# Does Xcode 11 and its new frameworks like SwiftUI demand changes to .gitignore?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, gitignore

I peaked into the .gitignore file that was in the SwiftUI example projects and found this. Should I add it to the current swift,macos template I pull from git? I'm not so concerned as I am curious whether it's superfluous.

I have copied and pasted it under the templates ##Various Settings `xcuserdata/`

---

This is what I copied:
**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/*
!**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata

**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/*
!**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings

**/*.playground/playground.xcworkspace/*
!**/*.playground/playground.xcworkspace/xcshareddata

**/*.playground/playground.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/*
!**/*.playground/playground.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. `.gitignore` tells git which files (or patterns) it should ignore. It's usually used to avoid committing transient files from your working directory.

You can find an official gitignore example for Swift [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore). You can use it, by default ;)

I also recommend reading about `git`: [What is git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F)